# Facebook like XFBML in double

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, xfbml

I would like to add an facebook like button in my page by using this XFBML:

```
<fb:like send="false" width="90" show_faces="false" layout="button_count" href="http://www.google.fr"><fb:like>
```

But it appear 2 line of like button:

```
[Like] Be the first of your friends to like this.
[Like]{176k]
```

I would like just to keep the second one. How Could I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't close your `<fb:like>` tag with a `/`:

```
<fb:like send="false" width="90" show_faces="false" layout="button_count" 
   href="http://www.google.fr"></fb:like>
```

Comment: oh my god! Thanks I dont think that I could find it that fast :)